# Qt installer framework undo Mkdir operations

Tags: qt, undo, qt-installer

I use qt installer framework to create installer. On installation step I called 
`component.addOperation("Mkdir", dataDir); // dataDir is a dataLocationDir like C:\Users\Stranger\AppData\Local\MyAppName`

When my installed program working it put some folders and files into dataLocationDir, at this way UNDO step of "Mkdir" operation does not work correctly when i runned uninstall. I try use "Execute" command like this:

`component.addOperation("Execute", "mkdir " + dataDir, "UNDOEXECUTE", "del /S /F" + dataDir);`

and also i tried

`component.addOperation("Execute", "cmd /C mkdir " + dataDir, "UNDOEXECUTE", "cmd /C del /S /F" + dataDir);`

but this methods cancel with error "Could not start: 'mkdir my/path'(No program defined)"

Comment: Some progress, but it still does not work. Now i write: <code>component.addOperation("Execute", "cmd",  "/C", "mkdir", dataDir, "UNDOEXECUTE", "cmd ", "/C", "rmdir",  "/S", /Q", dataDir);</code>. But it return error message "Execution failed (Unexpected exit code 1): cmd /C mkdir C:\User\Staranger\AppData\Local\MyPath"

Answer (score 0):

You said you tried both

```
component.addOperation("Execute", "mkdir " + dataDir, "UNDOEXECUTE", "del /S /F" + dataDir);
```

and

```
component.addOperation("Execute", "cmd", "/C", "mkdir", dataDir, "UNDOEXECUTE", "cmd ", "/C", "rmdir", "/S", /Q", dataDir);
```

I think the right way is the first one, with the syntax of the second:

```
component.addOperation("Execute", "mkdir", dataDir, "UNDOEXECUTE", "del", "/S", "/F", dataDir);
```

The first one did not work because you have to separate the executable from the arguments. If Qt gets a single string, it assumes it's your executable full path.
The second one actually should work, since you can run (in a cmd for instance) "cmd /c mkdir yourPath" and it works as intended. Anyway, I've tested and used the solution I propose. If it doesn't work, make sure you escape your backslashes correctly in your path.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem.

In short it looks like the operations on directories of QtIFW are buggy.

Under Windows I've solved in this way:

1. I've created a batch file which manages an input argument "add" during the installation and an input argument "delete" when during the deinstallation.
2. I've put it in the resource file of the installer.
3. In the constructor of the component I am moving this script to the installation directory:

   installer.performOperation("Copy", ["://myfile.bat", installer.value("TargetDir")]);
4. In createOperations of Component there is:

   component.addOperation("Execute", ["cmd", "/c", "@TargetDir@\\myfile.bat", "add", "workingDirectory=@TargetDir@", "UNDOEXECUTE", "cmd", "/c", "@TargetDir@\\myfile.bat", "delete", "workingDirectory=@TargetDir@"]);
5. In finishPageCallback of Controller I remove the batch in this way:

   installer.performOperation("Delete", installer.value("TargetDir") + "\\myfile.bat"));

Answer (score 0):

This is an installer [error](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTIFW-1099?gerritIssueStatus=All) in the operation of the Mkdir operation.

I got around this using the controller script.

```
Controller.prototype.FinishedPageCallback = function()
{
    if (installer.isUninstaller() && installer.status == QInstaller.Success) {

        var pathToconfigMyapp = QDesktopServices.storageLocation(QDesktopServices.GenericDataLocation) + "\\Myapp";


        if(installer.fileExists(pathToconfigMyapp) === true){
            installer.executeDetached("cmd",["/c", "rd", "/q", "/s", pathToconfigMyapp]);
        }

        gui.clickButton(buttons.FinishButton);
    }
```